# helloworld.sh on x-wrt webif gives me a 403 unauthorized

Tags: shell, openwrt

I am trying to customize the webif v. 0.3-4895 package on openwrt-10.03.1-rc3 (backfire).

I have a functional webif and I am trying to follow [this wiki entry](http://wiki.x-wrt.org/index.php/Programmer%27s_Guide_to_the_Webif#Example%3a_Hello_world_page)

I copied info.sh to helloworld.sh and edited .categories and the ##WEBIF line
but I dont see any change in the menu and when i call helloworld.sh I get a 403 on my browser.
(the other pages are functional, I can edit and add text to info.sh).

Has anyone any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I am a bit of a newbie today: I missed execution permissions
chmod a+x helloworld.sh